# Firebase in Flutter, make loading more appealing

Tags: firebase, flutter

So I am working on a message app, i was thinking about a few methods to make the loading of data more appealing, because now, it just loads in really "ugly". basically it just jumps when new data gets added. I was think about just at the beginning really load all the data but store that data in lists to then later manipulate those instead of building everything again. What would your approach be? Am I not thinking correct there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was think about just at the beginning really load all the data but store that data in lists to then later manipulate those instead of building everything again.

That is how I've implemented it, storing updates as the state updates in the app. But this only works if all data is personal so you don't have two persons changing the same data at the same time so you get overrides in firebase.

If you have multiple changes to the same dataset it is better to work with realtime data imo. Read more at [Firestore realtime changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)

Comment: yeah ok so i am on the right path, because the data is private anyways and no one is really chatting with each other, at least in realtime, I guess this is really the best strategy to go for